# \hspace does not work before longtable

Tags: spacing, longtable

The following code produces the image below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\hspace{-14mm}
\begin{tabular}{p{2mm}p{122mm}p{2mm}}\hline
  &\parbox{122mm}{\lipsum[1]}& \\\hline
  &\parbox{122mm}{\lipsum[1]}& \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: Imgur]

Now, I want to do the same with a longtable, however, the `\hspace` command seems to not cause any effect. Here is an example of it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\hspace{-14mm}
\begin{longtable}{p{2mm}p{122mm}p{2mm}}\hline
  &\parbox{122mm}{\lipsum[1]}& \\\hline
  &\parbox{122mm}{\lipsum[1]}& \\\hline
  &\parbox{122mm}{\lipsum[1]}& \\\hline
  &\parbox{122mm}{\lipsum[1]}& \\\hline
\end{longtable}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: Imgur]

Any idea of how can I do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with this `\hspace{-14mm}`?

Comment: Just to move the whole table to the left.

Comment: even for a normal tabular using a negative hspace in that way is not a good way to try to align the left margin. You have a parindent (15pt by default) then a negative space of -14pt, then a word space (variably but around .3em usually) then the tabcolsep to the left of tabular (6pt by default) so this will or will not make the text in the table seem aligned depending on all kinds of accidental effects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the length \LTleft, if you want to change the position of the longtable (as default it is centered).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\setlength\LTleft{-14mm}
\begin{longtable}{p{2mm}p{122mm}p{2mm}}\hline
  &\parbox{122mm}{\lipsum[1]}& \\\hline
  &\parbox{122mm}{\lipsum[1]}& \\\hline
  &\parbox{122mm}{\lipsum[1]}& \\\hline
  &\parbox{122mm}{\lipsum[1]}& \\\hline
\end{longtable}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```